# Why is java.lang.NullPointerException happening in retrieving all the documents from a collection

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, document

I'm trying to retrieve all my documents from a collection name Items and i'm just pasting the code given by google to retrieve all documents from a collection.But Every time i run it always produce  java.lang.NullPointerException. Can u tell me why

I used the code that is given by goggle to retrieve all collections from fire store.But unfortunately it didnt work

```
db.collection("Items")
            .get()
            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Every time i run it shows this Error

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.collection(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference

Comment: In the `db.collection(...)` call the `db` object is `null`, so you should have a look at how and where you are (or aren't) instantiating `db` as a valid `FirebaseFirestore` object. And of course add the relevant code to the question, if you then still need some help with the problem.

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error? Please responde with @AlexMamo